# Can we Walk for few minutes during Glucose tolerance test?

Tags: diabetes, procedural-expectations, pre-diabetes, type-2-diabetes, procedural-behavior

Can we walk slightly for 5 to 7 mins in every 1/2 hr after blood sample collection during 2 hrs 75gm glucose tolerance test?

Does walking have an effect on the GTT?

Below is the sample test result and to know whether this patient suffering from diabetes.

Fasting : 114 mg% . 1/2 hr : 190 mg%. 1 hr : 235 mg% .

1 1/2 hrs : 180 mg% . 2 hrs : 157 mg%.

Is this test valid or invalid.

Comment: Right now, your question is off-topic because you are asking for personal diagnosis. However, if you were to remove that part and simply leave your question as *"does walking have an effect on glucose tolerance tests"*, it would be acceptable and actually an interesting question.